# Compatible version of Allegro with my GCC compiler

Tags: 32-bit, gcc, mingw, code-blocks

I am using **32 bit version of code::blocks 17.12** with **TDM-GCC version 5.1.0-3** on **windows 7 ultimate 32 bit**. I was using Allegro 5 (**allegro-mingw-gcc6.2.0-x86-static-5.2.2**). It worked completely fine. I followed all the steps necessary to run allegro with codeblocks. Everything worked just fine.

Then I uninstalled and reinstalled the same TDM-GCC. And downloaded a different version of Allegro 5 (**allegro-i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-7.4.0-posix-dwarf-dynamic-5.2.5.0**) from https://github.com/liballeg/allegro5/releases/tag/5.2.5.0. I did all the process which I did in the last used version. But this time it displays a message box which gives me an error while compiling the code.

The error goes like this "**The procedure entry point _divmoddi64 could not be located in the dynamic link library libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll**".

In the build log this message is shown "**Process terminated with status -1073741511**"

**Code used.**

```
#include <allegro5/allegro5.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    al_init();
    return 0;
}
```

i have google both the error and build log error. But i was simply unable to find any solution. It certainly looks like a version mismatch to me. Please help me solving this error.

***note: i wanted to add the tag "allegro5" but i didn't had the required reputation***

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670169/.

Comment: @Biswapriyo please can you explain briefly what are you trying to say ? I am kinda noob when it comes to compiler stuff.

Comment: Will there be any big difference if I don't use codeblocks? I use msys2/mingw-w64.

Comment: @Biswapriyo as i said earlier, i am a total noob when it comes to compilers. I have been using codeblocks for quite sometime now and I plan to continue using it. So codeblocks it is please.